# NodeJS reading/writing files to network drive

Tags: node.js

I have a script that writes files to disk using fs createWriteStream.

What I am trying to achieve now is write those files to a shared network drive.

With a directory like so - //hostname/scratch/reece

I am running this script on windows, but this application will sit on ubnutu/rhel when I deploy it.

This is a crucial part of this script so any suggestions on how I can write to a network drive would be great.

The same would go for reading from a network drive and sending that back via HTTP.

Keeping in mind there would likely be hundreds of thousands of requests to write to this drive through my nodejs api, so I would like to avoid relying on background processes to handle the file transfer.

Any ideas on approach?

Comment: You will have to connect the drive to your server using a technology appropriate for that particular OS (may be different on Ubuntu vs. Windows).  You can then address that server through whatever OS mount tech it uses.  In Windows, you can use either a drive letter or a UNC path.  On Ubuntu, perhaps a mounted volume. This is one case where you aren't likely to make the exact same setup work on Windows vs. Ubuntu.  If you put the appropriate root path name into a config file, the rest of your code can probably be identical.  Beyond this, it isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: I will give that a go. I am developing an API for storing/retrieving documents while at the same time I am writing a script on windows for an adhoc extract that got me thinking about this issue. Actual API development is in a UNIX environment hence why I am asking from that perspective

Comment: I was able to access the drive through \\\\hostname\\scratch\\reece\\ and that worked perfectly. Mounting did not work. If you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it

Comment: That worked perfectly Reece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to connect the drive to your server using a technology appropriate for that particular OS (may be different on Ubuntu vs. Windows). You can then address that server through whatever OS mount tech it uses.

In Windows, you can use either a drive letter or a UNC path. On Ubuntu, perhaps a mounted network file system volume.

This is one case where you aren't likely to make the exact same setup work on Windows vs. Ubuntu. If you put the appropriate root path name into a config file, the rest of your code can probably be identical. Beyond this, it isn't clear what you're asking.