# Access remote files through NodeJS

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am sharing a folder named **downloads** on a remote machine. It can be accessed through

**file://{IP Address}/downloads**

In my protractor tests, I just have to check whether the file exists on the remote machine. However, my **fs** module in NodeJS always returns false.

How do I check, whether the file exists in NodeJS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS reading/writing files to network drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522503/nodejs-reading-writing-files-to-network-drive)

Comment: A workaround you might want to try is to symlink the network folder to a "real" folder. That MAY make it work.

Comment: Mapping to a network drive will work. But I am running my protractor job on so many machines.